# Firebase Authentication - Retrieve Custom Claims key for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

A custom claim `luid` has been added to the Firebase Authentication from the backend, I'm looking for a way to access this key from the front end for an iOS application.

First I need to check if the key exists and if it exists then get its value.

What have I tried? Everything under `Auth.auth().currentUser`

Attaching a picture of the decoded JWT data, which shows the key `luid`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the custom claims this way:

```
user.getIDTokenResult(completion: { (result, error) in
  guard let luid = result?.claims?["luid"] as? NSNumber else {
    // luid absent
    return
  }
  //Check for value here and use if-else
})
```

Detailed explanation can be found in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#swift)

Answer (score 0):

This will display a Dictionary with all the keys available for the current user.

```
 Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenResult(completion: { (authresult, error) in
     print("CurrentUser Keys", authresult!.claims.keys)
})
```

This will return `Bool` value based on a particular key's availability

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.getIDTokenResult(completion: { (authresult, error) in
     print("CurrentUser Keys", authresult!.claims.keys.contains("luid"))
})
```